# reading geometry of a shapefile

Tags: python, geometry, arcgis

I have a shapefile of US Cities and I want to get the X and Y coordinate of EACH city in that shapefile. I've tried this:

```
for city in city_cursor: 
    geom = city.Shape 
    point = geom.getPart() 
    citylist_City_Name.append(city.CITY_NAME) 
    citylist_Country.append(city.CNTRY_NAME) 
    citylist_Admin.append(city.ADMIN_NAME) 
    citylist_Population.append(city.Population) 
    citylist_X_Coor.append(geom.point.X) 
    citylist_Y_Coor.append(geom.point.Y)
```

but I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/workd.py", line 43, 
in citylist_X_Coor.append(geom.point.X) AttributeError: 'PointGeometry' object 
has no attribute 'point'
```

I don't really understand the error message? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Now that I can read your code, you probably want to change:

```
citylist_X_Coor.append(geom.point.X) 
citylist_Y_Coor.append(geom.point.Y)
```

to

```
citylist_X_Coor.append(point.X) 
citylist_Y_Coor.append(point.Y)
```

since you already extracted `point` from `geom` using `geom.getPart()`.